# Using ant patterns to match on path variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have several different controllers, configured with endpoints like below.  Where `{id}` is a numeric `@PathVariable`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/noun1/noun2/{id}/verb1")
@RequestMapping(value = "/noun1/noun2/{id}/verb2")
@RequestMapping(value = "/noun1/noun2/{id}/verb3/verb4")
@RequestMapping(value = "/noun1/noun2/noun3/verb5")
```

Using `HttpSecurity`, I want to implement security around all endpoints that have `{id}` in them.  So I created an ant pattern like this:

```
"/noun1/noun2/{id}/**"
```

The ant pattern is correctly matching on the endpoints with `{id}` in them.  However, the ant pattern is also matching on the last endpoint, setting `id = noun3`.  Is there a way with ant patterns to only match the endpoints containing `{id}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How your ant pattern should be depends on what `{id}` can be. The `{id}` in your ant matcher is not directly related to your `{id}` in your `RequestMapping` annotation.

Spring Security just checks, with the ant matcher, whether the path matches the provided pattern. In your case `{id}` matches any string and stores the matched value in a `URI template variable` named `id` for later use.

To specify the what is considered an `{id}` you can provide an regex. If your id consists of digits your matcher could be `"/noun1/noun2/{regex:\\d+}/**"`:

```java
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher;

class AntMatcherTest {

  @Test
  void antMatcher() {
    AntPathMatcher antPathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();
    String pattern = "/noun1/noun2/{id:\\d+}/**";

    assertFalse(antPathMatcher.match(pattern, "/noun1/noun2/noun3/verb5"));
    assertTrue(antPathMatcher.match(pattern, "/noun1/noun2/1/verb1"));
    assertTrue(antPathMatcher.match(pattern, "/noun1/noun2/2/verb2"));
    assertTrue(antPathMatcher.match(pattern, "/noun1/noun2/3/verb3/verb4"));
  }
}
```